# Bash script works via terminal but not via main menu

Tags: bash, scripting, gnome

When I run a bash script from terminal or nautilus, it works properly, but when I run it via gnome's 'Main Menu', it returns an error.

`read -p "" -n1 selection`

This is the line, that return the following error:

`/usr/local/bin/php-version.sh: 9: read: Illegal option -n`

But when I run the script via terminal (`./file.sh`), there's no problem with this

The Main Menu entry is `bash usr/local/bin/php-version.sh`

File permissions are 755, owner is root.

**EDIT:**

*/usr/local/bin/php-version.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo echo -e "sudo/root permission: \e[32mOkay\e[0m"

echo -e "Type \e[2m5\e[0m to change from php version \e[1m7 \e[0mto \e[1m5\e[0m"
echo -e "Type \e[2m7\e[0m to change from php version \e[1m5 \e[0mto \e[1m7\e[0m"

echo -en "\e[1mSelect: \e[0m"
read -p "" -n1 selection
echo

case "$selection" in
    "5") 
        sudo a2dismod php7.0 >> /dev/null
        sudo a2enmod php5 >> /dev/null
        sudo a2query -m php5
        ;;
    "7")
        sudo a2dismod php5 >> /dev/null
        sudo a2enmod php7.0 >> /dev/null
        sudo a2query -m php7.0
        ;;
    *)
        sudo echo -e "\e[91mInvalid input: \e[39m$selection\e[0m"
        echo -en "\e[2mPress Enter..."; sed -n q </dev/tty
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

echo "Restarting apache2..."; sudo service apache2 restart    
echo -en "\e[2mPress Enter..."; sed -n q </dev/tty
```

*/usr/local/bin/test.sh* (where the `read` command always works)

```
#!/bin/bash

ps aux | grep $$ | grep -v grep

read -p "" -n1 test

echo -e "\n"

env

$SHELL
```

Comment: Could you write a simple debugging script `test.sh` to check whether gnome does really start a non-posix bash where `read -n` should work? test.sh could do `env` to see all variables and `ps aux | grep $$ | grep -v grep` to see which shell is used.

Comment: `ps aux | grep $$ | grep -v grep` returns

`scriptim  3669  0.0  0.0  13236  2844 pts/1    Ss+  00:08   0:00 /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/test.sh` (terminal)

`scriptim  5188  0.0  0.0  13236  2852 pts/1    Ss+  00:15   0:00 bash /usr/local/bin/test.sh` (Main Menu)


POSIXLY_CORRECT is not defined

Comment: @rudimeier yes, both terminal and main menu

Comment: So the problem must be located inside `php-version.sh`. Could you post both the working `test.sh` and the bad `php-version.sh`? (Edit your question.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see why `read "" -n1 selection` works in terminal and not from the menu. The error message seems misleading too. However the correct bash syntax should be

```
read -n 1 selection
```

You may change that line in `php-version.sh`.

Beside that the whole scripts looks a bit strange. Most of the `sudo` commands should not be `sudo`. Anyways that wasn't the question.

Comment: Fixed the sudo thing, my fault - this had different reasons